# Reference on the solution of Liouville's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0006011) reference, regarding statistical mechanics of recurrent neural networks. In section 2.1, a derivation of an equation for the time evolution of the magnetization $m$ is presented. Being $p_m(t)$ the probability of a certain magnetization at time $t$, it can be showed that
$$\frac{dp_m(t)}{dt} = -\frac{d}{dm}\{f(m)p_m(t)\}. \quad\quad (1)$$
The author just presents the solution of this equation, that he calls Liouville's equation, and from this he obtains the differential equation for the magnetization, but do not explain the steps to derive it. Is there a textbook or any reference on the solution of such equations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found the reference. Appendix F of the book "Theory of Neural Information Processing Systems - Coolen, Sollich and Reimer".